# BeautifulSoup returning [] after getting user input

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Upon asking the user for input it returns a empty list, I've tried looking at other answers with similar issues but none of them solved mine.

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
resp = requests.get(url).text
page = BeautifulSoup(resp, "html.parser")




def Get_Links():
        
        inp = input("Enter data you wish to find: ")
        datavar = page.find_all(inp, 'a', href=True)
       
        
        
        print(datavar)
```

Result:

```
[]
```

Comment: What do you expect `inp` to be? A html element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass as `string` argument to the `find_all` function for the text (text inside the anchor tag) search.

```
def Get_Links():
    inp = input("Enter data you wish to find: ")
    datavar = page.find_all('a', href=True, string=inp)
    return datavar
```

Execution:

```
In [1]: Get_Links()
Enter data you wish to find: 2012
Out[1]: [<a href="/wiki/2012" title="2012">2012</a>]
```